# Flash Player Debug for ARM Linux?

Tags: linux, arm, flash

Where can I download the content debugger version of the flash player for ARM Linux? This must exist somewhere, but I'm having no luck googling this up for download anywhere. I'm running ubuntu 10.4 on a thin client (Wyse T50).

All/any tips appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that a debug player for this platform does not exist